# Multivariate Empirical Probability Measure?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Assume we have a sample $\{x^{1},..., x^{N}\}$, where each $x^{i}$ is a $K$-dim vector.

How would I write the multivariate empirical probability measure?

If the vectors were 1-dim, then I would write it as $\mu = \frac{1}{N} \sum^N_{i=1}\delta{(\cdot, x^{i})}$, where $\delta{(x, x^{i})}$ is 1 for $x=x^{i}$ and zero everywhere else.

For the general $K$-dim case, I was thinking something along the lines of $\mu^K = \frac{1}{N} \sum^N_{i=1}\delta(x, x^{i})$ but now delta receives vectors.

Is this ok, or am I missing something?

Comment: You could do that but it seems like it won't tell you much about the shape of the distribution, right? This is already the case in the 1-dimensional situation.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer I'm not exactly sure why you say it won't tell us the shape... could you please elaborate on that? thanks in advance. ;)

Comment: Well, let's say you have a normally distributed random variable $X \sim N(0,1)$ and you have $10$ observations $x_1,\ldots,x_{10}$ of $X$. Then the empirical distribution won't be a bell curve; rather, it's going to be $0$ everywhere except on $10$ points, where it has a really tall peak. In some sense it's a fairly good approximation (taking the cdf will yield something which looks like the cdf of your original distribution)... I guess my remark becomes redundant depending on what exactly you want out of the empirical approximation.